# Can I open socket in PHP from a specific IP (if the machine has two IPs)?

Tags: php, sockets, phpmailer, fsockopen

I'm using PHPMailer and it uses `fsockopen` to access the SMTP server.

But the machine has two IPs with different reverse DNS records. So in email headers I got the following:

```
Received: from one-server.tld (HELO another-server.tld) ...
```

I need to hide `one-server.tld` in favor of `another-server.tld`. But I need both IPs with their current RDNS settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think its not possible using `fsockopen`. But its possible in `curl`, `fopen` and `stream` functions.  What you need is [stream_socket_client()](http://php.net/stream_socket_client) function.

Here are some ways to achieve it.

1. Using context parameters which can be used in fopen function family and stream function family. See the example.

   ```
   $opts = array(
       'socket' => array(
           'bindto' => '192.168.0.100:0',
       ),
   );
   // create the context...
   $context = stream_context_create($opts);
   $contents = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
   ```

   Also [stream_socket_client](http://php.net/stream_socket_client)

   ```
   $fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://www.example.com:80", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $opts);
   if (!$fp) {
       echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
   } else {
       fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
       while (!feof($fp)) {
           echo fgets($fp, 1024);
       }
       fclose($fp);
   }
   ```
2. Using [socket_bind](http://php.net/socket_bind). PHP.NET got a simple example [here](http://php.net/socket_bind).

Comment: Thanks a lot! `stream_socket_client` allows to keep the other code unchanged.